# ValidationException while executing bash

Tags: bash, aws-cli, aws-ssm

Here i am trying to retrieve latest ami id for k8s worker node.

i have written a bash script for the same, every time i run this script it return errors.

Please set VERSION=v1.23 before running script

note: when we run the command individually it works.

```
#!/bin/bash

VERSION=$1

SOURCE_AMI_ID=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name /aws/service/eks/optimized-ami/${VERSION}/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id --region us-west-2 --query "Parameter.Value" --output text)
SOURCE_AMI_NAME=$(aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ${SOURCE_AMI_ID} | jq -r '.Images[0].Name')
AMI_NAME=$(echo "${SOURCE_AMI_NAME}" | sed 's/amazon/kube-infra/g')
jq -n \
        --arg source_ami_id "${SOURCE_AMI_ID}" \
        --arg source_ami_name "${SOURCE_AMI_NAME}" \
        --arg cp_ami_name "${CP_AMI_NAME}" \
        '{source_ami_id: $source_ami_id, source_ami_name: $source_ami_name, ami_name: $ami_name}'
```

## error:

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetParameter operation: Parameter name: can't be prefixed with "ssm" (case-insensitive). If formed as a path, it can consist of sub-paths divided by slash symbol; each sub-path can be formed as a mix of letters, numbers and the following 3 symbols .-_

## how i am running the above script

% ./build-versions.sh

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetParameter operation: Parameter name: can't be prefixed with "ssm" (case-insensitive). If formed as a path, it can consist of sub-paths divided by slash symbol; each sub-path can be formed as a mix of letters, numbers and the following 3 symbols .-_

Comment: Since you VERSION comes from $1, please also include how you ran this script.

Comment: When running `aws ssm get-parameter --name /aws/service/eks/optimized-ami/${VERSION}/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id --region us-west-2`, I only got "An error occurred (ParameterNotFound) when calling the GetParameter operation:".

Comment: when i run the same command on bash shell : aws ssm get-parameter --name /aws/service/eks/optimized-ami/${VERSION}/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id --region us-west-2 --query "Parameter.Value" --output text
ami-06666dbb84908f946

Comment: You need to run your script as  `./build-versions.sh v1.23`. Otherwise where is "v1.23" from?

Comment: Actually I note that for me it needs to be "1.23" instead of "v1.23". Not sure how it worked for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

```bash
aws ssm get-parameter \
  --name /aws/service/eks/optimized-ami/v1.23/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id \
  --region us-west-2
```

Gives me error (ParameterNotFound). I need to use "1.23" instead of "v1.23" to get a valid response, namely

```bash
aws ssm get-parameter \
  --name /aws/service/eks/optimized-ami/1.23/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id \
  --region us-west-2
```

Below I assume you will also use "1.23".

---

Setting `VERSION=1.23` before running the script is not useful in this case. In your script, `VERSION=$1`, which means it sets `VERSION` to the first argument of the script. Hence, you should run

```bash
./build-versions.sh 1.23
```

Instead of

```bash
VERSION=1.23
./build-versions.sh
```

If you really want to set it outside of your script, then you need to set it with `export VERSION=1.23`, and remove the `VERSION=$1` line.

Comment: ./build-versions.sh v1.23 this looks nice

Comment: @SatyamPandey It only works for me if I use "1.23" instead of "v1.23". Please make sure. If I use "1.23" I get the same AMI ID that you put earlier in question comment.

Comment: ohk i will check in an hour or two and update, thanks for taking a look here much appriciated